# Windows toast is not shown on one machine but works on several others

Tags: c++, windows, toast

I use Toast++ from P.J. Naughter. This works perfect on 99% of all machines.

But I have one machine, where the Windows toasts don't pop up. Other applications like DropBox and Outlook show the notification toasts.

I inserted TRACE messages and I can see with DebugView that all calls to Show the toast succeed. So there must be something in the notification center, that blocks my messages.

Even in the list of applications in the System Settings doesn't show up.

I searched the registry for the used Application User Model ID `MySoftware.MyApp.Main` but I can't find any entry in the registry. The HKCU entry doesn't contain an entry.

Any further hints that can lead me to the problem, or the reason, why the Windows toasts are blocked?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the AUMI entry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppUserModelId\` was missing.

Should have been created by the setup, but for some reasons it was deleted or never created at the customer.

Without this entry no toasts are shown and the application is missing in the system settings list for the windows information center.